# The best way to generate market scenarios

Tags: risk-management, risk-models

1. What general approaches could you recommend for modeling spot rates(for different maturities) and forward rates?(eg for LIBOR)
2. I need to generate scenarios for term-structure of interest rates.
3. What is an optimal way to generate scenarios for interest rates when the number of scenarios is restricted(# of paths is bounded)? I want to build optimal ensemble of trajectories.

Comment: This question is too broad / not specific. Can you please elaborate on the context, i.e. what are you trying to do, is this for a Monte Carlo simulation, what is the asset type, what are your risk factors?

Comment: Hi, jamoor. Thanks for your answer. I've corrected the question.

Comment: The question is still too broad, there are books on this :-) 
As for 3 if you're referring to numerical efficiency then try in general variance reduction methods; among those applicable in most contexts are stratified sampling or (its advanced high-dimensional version) Quasi Monte Carlo, they can be very tricky though.

Comment: @Quartz is right, I would like to propose this question in two parts: (1, 2) and 3. This will still be broad but I hope answerable.

Comment: Not reopening for now but as said, edits are welcome.